# Integration a function with a polynomial for a denominator

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

**QUESTION**

The following differential equation describes the amount of $x$ of KOH after time $t$:

$$\frac{dx}{dt} = k \left(n_1 - \frac{x}{2}\right)^2 \left(n_2 - \frac{x}{2}\right)^2 \left(n_3 - \frac{3x}{4}\right)^3$$

where $k$ is the velocity constant of the reaction of the reaction. If $k = 6.22 \times 10^{-19}$, $n_1 = 1 \times 10^3$, $n_2 = 2 \times 10^3$ and $n_3 = 3 \times 10^3$. Use Runge-Kutta method of order 4 to determine how many units of potassium hydroxide will be formed after 0.2s.

**ATTEMPT**
I began by rearranging the equation so it could be a differential equation of form:

$$\left[\left(n_1 - \frac{x}{2}\right)^2 \left(n_2 - \frac{x}{2}\right)^2 \left(n_3 - \frac{3x}{4}\right)^3\right]^{-1} \, dx = k \, dt$$

My problem is with the left hand side of the equation.

I expanded the equation and got a polynomial of the form $$ a - bx + cx^2 - dx^3 + ex^4 - fx^5 + gx^6 - hx^7 $$

where $ a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h$ are really large constants.

So I have no idea how to integrate $$ \frac{dx}{a - bx + cx^2 - dx^3 + ex^4 - fx^5 + gx^6 - hx^7}$$

Please help...

**MY CONCERNS**

So do I even have to integrate it? Or can I leave it as:

$$\left[\left(n_1 - \frac{x}{2}\right)^2 \left(n_2 - \frac{x}{2}\right)^2 \left(n_3 - \frac{3x}{4}\right)^3\right]^{-1} \, dx = k \, dt ?$$

But and then what? How do I proceed with the Runge-Kutta method?

This is the Runge-Kutta method:

$$ t_0 = \alpha$$
$$ k_1 = hf(x_i, t_i)$$
$$ k_2 = hf\left(x_i + \frac{h}{3}, y_i + \frac{k_1}{3}\right),$$
$$ k_3 = hf\left(x_i + \frac{2h}{3}, y_i + \frac{2k_2}{3}\right),$$
$$ y_{i+1} = y_i + \frac{1}{4}(k_1 + 3k_3)$$ for each $i = 0,1,\ldots,N-1$

I seriously have no idea where to go from here.

Comment: I don't think anyone has any idea how to integrate that in closed form in general.  You need to use Runge-Kutta or something similar to determine what you seek.

Comment: Closed form looks tough, unless you express the LHS in partial fractions using the nice factorisation you already have, and get lucky.  Wolframalpha shows the partial fraction form as well as the integral.  However numerical methods may be easier still.

Comment: @Siyanda : You repeatedly wrote "k dt" with a space between k and dt, making it look as if you intended it to get rendered as $k\,dt$, with such a space.  That doesn't work in TeX code in math mode.  You have to include something do indicate spacing, as in k\,dt or k~dt.  I edited accordingly, and also used \left( and \right) so that the parentheses have appropriate sizes.

Answer (score 2):

The trick is not to expand the denominator and integrate it using a rather long partial fraction decomposition. If you go through this you will find that 
$$\frac{4}{(n_1-n_2)^2(n_1-n_3)^3(x-2n_1)}+\frac{4}{(n_1-n_2)^2(n_2-n_3)^3(x-2n_2)}+\frac{4}{(n_1-n_2)^2(n_1-n_3)^2(x-2n_3)^2}-\frac{8(n_1+n_2-2n_3)}{(n_1-n_3)^3(n_3-n_2)^3(x-2n_1)}-\frac{2(-5n_1+3n_2+2n_3)\log (x-2n_1)}{(n_1-n_2)^3(n_1-n_3)^4}-\frac{2(-3n_1+5n_2-2n_3)\log (x-2n_2)}{(n_1-n_2)^3(n_2-n_3)^4}-\frac{2(3n_1^2+4n_1n_2+3n_2^2-10n_1n_3-10n_2n_3+10n_3^2)\log (x-2n_3)}{(n_1-n_3)^4(n_2-n_3)^4}=kt$$
Now that you have a closed form solution to the equation you don't need to apply a numerical method like Runga-Kutta.